# How to navigate to a specific post in the mobile app?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, navigation

There doesn't seem to be a way to navigate to a specific question using the [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app). If there is, then it wasn't obvious to me. I tried entering the question number or URL into the search field, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Arie any updates, 2x8 weeks later? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Fixed in [tag:ios-app] 1.3.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is implemented, but there being no official answer posted I'm leaving instructions here.

Paste the URL or post ID of any question or answer into the search bar, then just tap the link below, which opens the post.

> [image]